# Monitorear Estatus de un Job

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, jobs

Estoy trabajando con `SQL SERVER 2014` y tengo 5 `Jobs` los cuales se ejecutan cada cierto tiempo, y de esos `jobs` quiero saber cual es su estatus, tengo entendido que eso lo  puedo revisar en la tabla de `msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity` la cosa es que no se esta registrando la infomacion de 2 `jobs` los cuales si se ejecutan, solo guarda infrmacion en la tabla de historial pero no en la de `activity` como puedo solucionar el problema, con la siguiente consulta solo me aparece la información  de 3 jobs pero faltan otros dos

```
    SELECT sj.Name, 
    CASE
        WHEN sja.start_execution_date IS NULL THEN 'Not running'
        WHEN sja.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL AND sja.stop_execution_date IS NULL THEN 'Running'
        WHEN sja.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL AND sja.stop_execution_date IS NOT NULL THEN 'Not running'
    END AS 'RunStatus'
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity sja
ON sj.job_id = sja.job_id
WHERE  session_id = (
    SELECT MAX(session_id) FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity);
```

> NOTA: LOS jobs si se ejecutan ya que realizan el proceso que les
>   corresponde